# Как сделать рандомный кастомный статус в discord.py? Я хочу, чтобы при запуске бота он ставил один из рандомных статусов, ранее написанных

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    variable_list = ["гляделки с Реди", "Minecraft Alpha", "Калькулятор", "самого себя"]
    status = {random.choice(variable_list)}
    print(f'Фаня Играет в {status}')
    print(f"{client.user} зашёл в сеть!")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game({random.choice(variable_list)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю можно сделать это примерно так:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    status = 0
    while True:
        status += 1
        if status == 1:
            #обновляем статус
        if status == 2:
            #обновляем статус
        if status == 3:
            #обновляем статус
            status = 0
        await asyncio.sleep(60) #статус будет меняться каждые 60 секунд.
```

Answer (score 0):

По мне, проще будет стандартным методом индекса по списку.

```
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game(variable_list[random.randint(0, len(test_list) - 1)]))
```